# How to get Information of an URL with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, discord.js

I am currently working on a discord bot, and I want a channel in my server,
where people can send link in, but I don't want to get them embeded automatically by the server,
I want to pull from that URL link all the informations I need to create myself (the bot will create) the embed,
the footer will say e.g. who suggested this link, I want the thumbnail to be matching the url's thumbnail (if it is pointing to a youtube vid e.g.)

The requirement is that I have a string with this URL,
can someone send me maybe a library where I can find the stuff,
because every url is different in its showing object (webpage, youtube vid, picture).

Also: is there a way to find out if a message is even containing a URL, or is *only* a URL.
I would like to filter my channel, so that only URL can be postet, and other messages will be deleted(I have a delete function)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try get some info from the page using the [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/) metadata or [Twitter Cards](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/markup), I think Discord use this to preview some links.

You have to disable "Embed Links" permissions to prevent Discord Embed appears and then send your embed.

You can get metadata from the page using [`node-fetch`](https://npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and [`cheerio`](https://npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Example:

```js
fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
.then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    console.log($("meta[property='og:title']")[0].attribs.content) // Returns OG Title from the page
```

Example with url from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141471/how-to-get-information-of-an-url-with-discord-js):

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")

fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141471/how-to-get-information-of-an-url-with-discord-js").then(res => res.text())
.then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    const title = $("meta[property='og:title']")[0] || $("meta[name='twitter:title']")
    const description = $("meta[property='og:description']")[0] || $("meta[name='twitter:description']")[0]
    const image = $("meta[property='og:image']")[0] || $("meta[name='twitter:image']")[0]
    const nothing = $("meta[property='og:thisdoesntexists']")[0] // Try get something that doesn't exists

    console.log(title ? title.attribs.content : "no title") // How to get Information of an URL with discord.js
    console.log(description ? description.attribs.content : "no description") // Short description
    console.log(image ? image.attribs.content : "no image") // https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded
    console.log(nothing ? nothing.attribs.content : "Literally, nothing") // Literally, nothing
})
```

Comment: hey thats a lot of help! But could you please also help me how to get the website's name? I watched for documentations but was really confused and lost... :/

Comment: What you mean with "website's name"? You want the website domain, like **google.com**, or just **google**?
And if my answer help de main question, please mark as correct

Comment: Only Google. I think I figured it out, it's site_name